# EMF namespace URI/prefix is null

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf-ecore, emf

I have to use EMF to create a EMF Generator Model from an existing ecore diagram, but it gives me namespace errors when trying to do so.

Here is is the screenshot of the two errors.

[image: Errors]

I think the error might be in the ecore file (XML), but I have no idea what to write, as I  have only been using the GUI tool to create the ecore model...

My ecorediag file is [here](https://gist.github.com/whirlwin/5347021), and my ecore file is [here](https://gist.github.com/whirlwin/5347275).

I have bad experience with EMF, as it has never worked smoothly without any hiccups, and this is yet another problem, however, I am forced to use it.

I tried Googling the errors, but only 9 and 8 hits were returned, most of which did not help solve the problem.

What do I need to edit in the ecorediag or ecore file to be able to generate my EMF Generator Model?

For the record, I am using Eclipse 4.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change nsURI in to "http: ///ecore_file_name.ecore" and nsPrefix into "ecore_file_name" it woks great

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to rewrite the whole project from scratch.

The approach was to carefully generate the genmodel for every change I made to the ecore file (adding/renaming/removing attributes/classes) to make sure nothing bad happened between any alterations to the model. By following this approach, you will be able to isolate the problem if something goes wrong.

However, I am still looking for another solution/answer other than rewriting everything.